# Execute Stored Procedure using current LightSwitch ConnectionString

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in a custom WebForm on my HTML LS Web Application, but i want to use the same ConnectionString that serverContext does to retreive data.

I have this C# Method to obtain ServerApplicationContext

```
private static ServerApplicationContext GetServerContext()
    {
        ServerApplicationContext serverContext = (LightSwitchApplication.ServerApplicationContext)ServerApplicationContext.Current;
        if (serverContext == null)
        {
            serverContext = (LightSwitchApplication.ServerApplicationContext)ServerApplicationContext.CreateContext();
        }
        return serverContext;
    }
```

I think the connection string might be accessible somewhere, i just don't know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
string _ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataSourceName"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("sp_StoredProcName", sqlconn);
sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlconn.Open();

SqlParameter sqlParam1 = sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", "ParamText");

SqlDataReader reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
```

This is how I execute Stored Procedures from LS Projects via WebApi2.